# how to filter who sends data from html file containing a form sent via post to a php file

Tags: php, html, forms, post

so when I try to send a data from html file form via post and set the action to my PHP file, it receives data without validating from whom it was sent. so I want to filter the data sent to my desired or trusted sites or html files.

Comment: so what method does major sites use? or they use ajax request and  is  it easier and more realiable?

Answer (score 1):

You need CSRFP - cross-site request forgery protection.

I've used https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP successfully in the past, very easy to implement & written by a member from here

Comment: so i must use the code from the repo, is it the only way? and what method does major sites use for this issue?

Comment: There are plenty of CSRFP libraries available, but yes to use that one, just download it, add it to your codebase & configure it - see the example at https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP#simple-usage

I don't know specifically which library major sites use, see the link to OWASP in Jess Nielsen's reply for others, but they all follow the same basic principle of adding a token to the form which you then validate upon submission.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax post request then you should check for isAjaxRequest as per your framework or you should try HTTP_REFERER of $_SERVER to check from where request is coming.

Comment: its not an ajax post request i use a simple html form with the method post

Answer (score 0):

To validate the sender of the form you can use a token.

This practice is commonly seen with CSRF protection. Most sites uses the Synchronizer Token Pattern. which adds a hidden input field with a md5 hash in it that your site also has stored in memory.

More information here: [OWASP CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern)